# ImportError libSDL2-2.0.so.0 in wxPython wx.adv

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, wxpython

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Python 3.6.9, wx.version: 4.0.7.post2 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5

When I import wx.adv, I get the error

ImportError: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I run:

```
sudo apt-file search  libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
```

I get:

```
libsdl-image1.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
libsdl-image1.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems I was missing some libraries :(

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install git curl libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0
```

and all is fine